# Creating a new column using case_when and %in% operator returns NA in R?

Tags: r

I am creating a new column using a vector value matching `%in% operator`, but it returns `NA` in the created column.

Any thoughts and solutions?

I used this chunk of code:

```
> head(GddIdwHumRes)
                   aggre_per     slope Intercept r.squared adj.r.squared
1       3_GDD.AS_sum_Season1     4.239      3525  0.048890     -0.019050
2       3_GDD.Ch_sum_Season1     3.438      4004  0.048950     -0.018980
3 3_gridded_idw2_sum_Season1    -1.834      6315  0.136600      0.074970
4      3_hum.AS.mean_Season1  -505.800      6463  0.004094     -0.067040
5      3_hum.Ch.mean_Season1 -1921.000      7535  0.061420     -0.005625
6        3_ndvi.mean_Season1  1562.000      5415  0.158600      0.098480
  fstatistic.value   pval  pearson Wilayah  Season
1          0.71960 0.4106  0.22110       I Season1
2          0.72050 0.4102  0.22120       I Season1
3          2.21600 0.1588 -0.36960       I Season1
4          0.05756 0.8139 -0.06399       I Season1
5          0.91610 0.3547 -0.24780       I Season1
6          2.63900 0.1266  0.39820       I Season1
> # Mutate a `WI` column 
> GddIdwHumRes <- GddIdwHumRes %>% 
+   mutate(WI = case_when(
+     aggre_per %in% 'GDD.AS_sum' ~ "GDD_AS_sum",
+     aggre_per %in% 'GDD.Ch_sum' ~ "GDD_Ch_sum",
+     aggre_per %in% 'gridded_idw2_sum' ~ "idw2_sum",
+     aggre_per %in% "hum.AS.mean" ~ "hum_AS_mean",
+     aggre_per %in% "hum.Ch.mean" ~ "hum_Ch_mean",
+     aggre_per %in% "ndvi.mean" ~ "ndvi_mean",
+     aggre_per %in% "spi_1" ~ "spi_1",
+     aggre_per %in% "spi_3" ~ "spi_3",
+     aggre_per %in% "spi_6" ~ "spi_6"
+   ))
> head(GddIdwHumRes)
                   aggre_per     slope Intercept r.squared adj.r.squared
1       3_GDD.AS_sum_Season1     4.239      3525  0.048890     -0.019050
2       3_GDD.Ch_sum_Season1     3.438      4004  0.048950     -0.018980
3 3_gridded_idw2_sum_Season1    -1.834      6315  0.136600      0.074970
4      3_hum.AS.mean_Season1  -505.800      6463  0.004094     -0.067040
5      3_hum.Ch.mean_Season1 -1921.000      7535  0.061420     -0.005625
6        3_ndvi.mean_Season1  1562.000      5415  0.158600      0.098480
  fstatistic.value   pval  pearson Wilayah  Season   WI
1          0.71960 0.4106  0.22110       I Season1 <NA>
2          0.72050 0.4102  0.22120       I Season1 <NA>
3          2.21600 0.1588 -0.36960       I Season1 <NA>
4          0.05756 0.8139 -0.06399       I Season1 <NA>
5          0.91610 0.3547 -0.24780       I Season1 <NA>
6          2.63900 0.1266  0.39820       I Season1 <NA>
```

And here is link to my dataset:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nyT1zlUrPRv3CwQpe_n13auKAKoGMJuG/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason we are getting all `NA` is because `%in%` looks for a fixed match and not substring match.  If we want to match based on substring, either use `grepl` (from `base R`) or `str_detect` (from `stringr`) to create logical vectors in `case_when`.

```
> head(GddIdwHumRes$aggre_per)
[1] "3_GDD.AS_sum_Season1"       "3_GDD.Ch_sum_Season1"       "3_gridded_idw2_sum_Season1" "3_hum.AS.mean_Season1"      "3_hum.Ch.mean_Season1"      "3_ndvi.mean_Season1"       
> head(GddIdwHumRes$aggre_per) %in% 'GDD.AS_sum'
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
> grepl('GDD.AS_sum', head(GddIdwHumRes$aggre_per))
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

As `%in%` returns `FALSE`, the `case_when` conditions are not met and the default case is returned i.e. `NA`

Based on the pattern showed, it may not even require `case_when` as we could directly extract the substring with `str_extract`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
GddIdwHumRes <- GddIdwHumRes %>% 
   mutate(WI = str_extract(aggre_per, "(GDD|ndvi|hum|gridded|spi).*(?=_Season)"))
```

-output

```
> GddIdwHumRes$WI
[1] "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum" "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"        "spi_1"            "spi_3"            "spi_6"           
 [10] "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum" "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"        "spi_1"            "spi_3"            "spi_6"           
 [19] "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum" "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"        "spi_1"            "spi_3"            "spi_6"           
 [28] "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum" "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"        "spi_1"            "spi_3"            "spi_6"           
 [37] "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum" "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"        "spi_1"            "spi_3"            "spi_6"           
 [46] "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum" "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"        "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum"
 [55] "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"        "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum" "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"       
 [64] "spi_1"            "spi_3"            "spi_6"            "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum" "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"       
 [73] "spi_1"            "spi_3"            "spi_6"            "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum" "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"       
 [82] "spi_1"            "spi_3"            "spi_6"            "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum" "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"       
 [91] "spi_1"            "spi_3"            "spi_6"            "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum" "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"       
[100] "spi_1"            "spi_3"            "spi_6"            "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum" "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"       
[109] "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum" "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"        "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum"
[118] "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"        "spi_1"            "spi_3"            "spi_6"            "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum"
[127] "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"        "spi_1"            "spi_3"            "spi_6"            "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum"
[136] "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"        "spi_1"            "spi_3"            "spi_6"            "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum"
[145] "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"        "spi_1"            "spi_3"            "spi_6"            "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum"
[154] "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"        "spi_1"            "spi_3"            "spi_6"            "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum"
[163] "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"        "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum" "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"       
[172] "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum" "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"        "spi_1"            "spi_3"            "spi_6"           
[181] "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum" "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"        "spi_1"            "spi_3"            "spi_6"           
[190] "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum" "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"        "spi_1"            "spi_3"            "spi_6"           
[199] "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum" "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"        "spi_1"            "spi_3"            "spi_6"           
[208] "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum" "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"        "spi_1"            "spi_3"            "spi_6"           
[217] "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum" "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"        "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum"
[226] "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"        "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum" "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"       
[235] "spi_1"            "spi_3"            "spi_6"            "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum" "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"       
[244] "spi_1"            "spi_3"            "spi_6"            "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum" "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"       
[253] "spi_1"            "spi_3"            "spi_6"            "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum" "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"       
[262] "spi_1"            "spi_3"            "spi_6"            "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum" "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"       
[271] "spi_1"            "spi_3"            "spi_6"            "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum" "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"       
[280] "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum" "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"        "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum"
[289] "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"        "spi_1"            "spi_3"            "spi_6"            "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum"
[298] "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"        "spi_1"            "spi_3"            "spi_6"            "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum"
[307] "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"        "spi_1"            "spi_3"            "spi_6"            "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum"
[316] "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"        "spi_1"            "spi_3"            "spi_6"            "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum"
[325] "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"        "spi_1"            "spi_3"            "spi_6"            "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum"
[334] "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"        "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum" "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"       
[343] "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum" "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"        "spi_1"            "spi_3"            "spi_6"           
[352] "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum" "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"        "spi_1"            "spi_3"            "spi_6"           
[361] "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum" "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"        "spi_1"            "spi_3"            "spi_6"           
[370] "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum" "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"        "spi_1"            "spi_3"            "spi_6"           
[379] "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum" "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"        "spi_1"            "spi_3"            "spi_6"           
[388] "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum" "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"        "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum"
[397] "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"        "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum" "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"       
[406] "spi_1"            "spi_3"            "spi_6"            "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum" "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"       
[415] "spi_1"            "spi_3"            "spi_6"            "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum" "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"       
[424] "spi_1"            "spi_3"            "spi_6"            "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum" "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"       
[433] "spi_1"            "spi_3"            "spi_6"            "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum" "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"       
[442] "spi_1"            "spi_3"            "spi_6"            "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum" "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"       
[451] "GDD.AS_sum"       "GDD.Ch_sum"       "gridded_idw2_sum" "hum.AS.mean"      "hum.Ch.mean"      "ndvi.mean"
```

---

If we want to use `case_when`, the `str_detect` code would be

```
GddIdwHumRe <- GddIdwHumRes %>% 
     mutate(WI = case_when(
         str_detect(aggre_per, 'GDD.AS_sum') ~ "GDD_AS_sum",
         str_detect(aggre_per, 'GDD.Ch_sum') ~ "GDD_Ch_sum",
         str_detect(aggre_per,'gridded_idw2_sum') ~ "idw2_sum",
         str_detect(aggre_per, "hum.AS.mean") ~ "hum_AS_mean",
         str_detect(aggre_per, "hum.Ch.mean") ~ "hum_Ch_mean",
         str_detect(aggre_per,"ndvi.mean")~ "ndvi_mean",
         str_detect(aggre_per,"spi_1") ~ "spi_1",
         str_detect(aggre_per, "spi_3") ~ "spi_3",
         str_detect(aggre_per, "spi_6") ~ "spi_6"
       ))
```